# Expressing the binomial coefficients in terms of factorials and simplify

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Expressing the binomial coefficients in terms of factorials and simplifying algebraically, show that:

(a) $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n-r+1}{r}\cdot \binom{n}{r-1}$

(b) $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n}{n-r}\cdot \binom{n-1}{r}$

(c) $n\binom{n-1}{r}=(r+1)\cdot \binom{n}{r+1}$

My attempts:

For (a) (we know by symmetry that $\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{r-1}$)
$$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n-r+1}{r}\cdot \frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!} = \frac{n!(n-r+1)}{r(r-1)!(n-r)!} = \frac{n!(n-r+1)}{r!(n-r)!}$$
However, I'm unsure of what to do with $n-r+1$, do I divide this from $(n-r)!$ but how as the $+1$ throws me off?

for (b)
$$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n}{n-r}\cdot \binom{n-1}{r} = \frac{n(n-1)n!}{r!(n+1-r)!}$$
Becuase $(n-r)\times(n-r)! = (n-r+1)!$ But what do I do with $n(n-1)$?

for (c)
$$n\binom{n-1}{r}=(r+1)\cdot \binom{n}{r+1} = \frac{(r+1)n!}{(r+1)!(n-r)!}=\frac{n!}{(r+1-1)!(n-r)!}$$

When I expand the LHS for (c) it looks awfully a lot similar to (b) for example:
$$\frac{n(n-1)n!}{r!(n-(r+1))!}$$

I would deeply appreciate some community support on the right way towards calculating the algebra for these binomial coefficients.

Comment: It is not generally true that $\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{r-1}$, but $\frac{n-r+1}r \binom n{r-1}$ $=\frac{n-r+1}r \frac {n!}{(r-1)!(n-r+1)!}$ $=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}=\binom n r$

Comment: Correct answer $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)}$.  If you got something else, it is wrong.  Your (a) is wrong $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$.  For (b) then numerator of the right term should be $n(n-1)!$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I know that for sure! Though I seem to be missing the steps to get it into that form. As for (b) I had thought about that though I wasn't sure on how to proceed to get it in the form $n!$

Comment: Typo error for (a) $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$  Let $s=n-r$ and you have  $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{s!(n-s)!}=\binom{n}{s}$

Comment: @herbsteinberg I think I misunderstood your previous comment but after checkin with (at)Mathlover I can see where I went wrong. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, ${n \choose r} \ne {n \choose r-1}$

To solve $(a)$, simply expand LHS.

$\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r! \cdot (n-r)!} = \frac{n!}{r \cdot  (r-1)! \cdot (n-r)!}$

Multiply numerator and denominator by $(n-r+1)$, then,

$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n-r+1}{r} \cdot \frac{n!}{(r-1)! \cdot (n-r+1)!} = \frac{n-r+1}{r} \cdot {n \choose r-1}$

You should be able to solve $(b)$ and $(c)$ also by expanding LHS and rearranging.

Comment: May I ask what the purpose behind including $+1$ in the calculation is for? I have seen examples of $\frac{n!}{(r-1)!\cdot (n-r)!} = \binom{n}{r-1}$ without the $+1$ in $(n-r)!$?

Comment: @Stackcans ${n \choose r} = \frac{n!}{r! (n-r)!}$. Now replace $r$ with $(r-1)$ then $r!$ becomes $(r-1)!$ and $(n-r)!$ becomes $(n-(r-1))!$. It is not true that $ \frac{n!}{(r-1)! (n-r)!} = {n \choose r-1}$

Comment: I see! Thank you for the clarification, it's definitely cleared my doubts. Also I have been implementing your strategy and here's what I have for (b): $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r-1)!(n-r)} = \frac{(n-1)!n}{r!(n-r-1)!(n-r)}$ which seems to work far better!

Comment: Yes (b) is correct. If you take $n/(n-r)$ out, the rest is ${n-1 \choose r}$

Comment: I know we discussed this before but I came across this identity: $r\binom{n}{r} = n\binom{n-1}{r-1}$, what we discussed was this identity not being true: $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} = \binom{n}{r-1}$. So when I start to expand the following identity: $\frac{rn!}{r!(n-r)!} \implies \frac{n(n-1)!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!}$ now there is no extra value 1 in the factor $(n-r)!$, wouldn't it in this case become $n\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ unless I have missed a key step?

Comment: @Stackcans yes that is correct $r {n \choose r} = n {n-1 \choose r-1}$

Comment: What we discussed was ${n \choose r} \ne {n \choose r-1}$

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. I was bogged down by the little details like $\pm 1$ in the factor.